# Hi, why does my output print a t§■a instead of a time

Tags: arrays, c, string

why is my output a t§■a? I am tring to

• initialize a string s1 with the string "Once upon a"
and a second string
s2 with the string "time",
• insert string s2 in front of "a" in string s1,
• trying to print after the substring "a",

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main(){
   char s1[]="once upon a ";
   char s2[]="time ";
   char subs[]="a ";

puts(s1);

   strcat(s1 , s2);

strcpy (s1,s1);

puts(s1);

   char *a = strstr( s1 , subs);
printf("%s",a);
}
```

Comment: You're accessing your arrays out of bounds. If you tell your compiler to check for that, you'll get an error: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fEs53WM3e

Comment: You've built `s1` so that it is just big enough to hold "once upon a".  What do you suppose `strcat(s1, s2)` is going to do ?   Where is it going to write "time "?

Comment: Try `char s1[1024]="once upon a ";`

Comment: Thankss I already got it. (Im a newbie and I was playing around with string cmd)

Answer (score 0):

The signature for main should be `int main(void)`.  `strcat(s1 , s2);` writes out of bound to `s1` which is undefined behavior.  `strcpy (s1,s1);` doesn't do anything.  Also reformatted your code for readability:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char s1[sizeof("once upon a time a ")]="once upon a ";
    char s2[]="time ";
    char subs[]="a ";
    puts(s1);
    strcat(s1 , s2);
    puts(s1);
    char *a = strstr( s1 , subs);
    printf("%s",a);
}
```

and the output is:

```
once upon a 
once upon a time 
a time
```